# declare variable to store linq entity for conditional statements

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am trying to look up record using if I have the key then use Find if not use Where

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    public bool DeactivatePrice(int priceId = 0, string sponsorUserName = "")
    {
        var prices = db.BeveragePrices;

        // if we have an id then find
        if (priceId != 0)
        {
           prices = prices.Find(priceId);
        }
        else
        {
            prices = prices.Where(b => b.UserCreated == sponsorUserName);
        }

        if (prices != null)
        {
            // do something
        }
        return true;
```

I get the following error for

```
prices = prices.Find(priceId);
```

Cannot convert app.Model.BeveragePrices from system.data.entity.dbset

I am copying the pattern from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3760965/2330272) but something must be different.

Comment: Seems you forgot to put a predicate inside the Find function call. See my answer for a fix and another option.

Comment: The `Find` method returns a single entity but you have `prices` implicitly typed as a collection. This will cause an error.

Comment: @Alla - I think you are right about the single entity. I'll add this to the answer. Tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you forgot to put a predicate inside the `Find` function call. Also you need to do `ToList` on the collection. The second option is a lot more efficient. The first one gets the whole collection before selection.

Another note commented by @Alla is that the find returns a single element. So I assume another declaration had been made for 'price' in the first option I state down here.

`price = prices.ToList.Find(b => b.PriceId == priceId);`

Or

`prices = prices.Select(b => b.PriceId == priceId);`

I assume the field name is **PriceId**.