# Using if / else in lambda expression in Where clause

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have this Code for Search.

```
public List<Tbl_Product> ProductSearch(DateTime startdate, DateTime enddate, string productname, int suply)
{
    var q = _db.Tbl_Product
            .Where(model => 
                model.DateReg == startdate && 
                model.DateReg == enddate)
            .Where(model => 
                model.ProductName.Contains(productname))
            .Where({});

}
```

Now I Need to insert this code in Last `Where` .

```
if(suply == 1)
{
    model.Suply > 0 ;
}
else
{
    model.Suply = 0;
}
```

How should I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing conditional 'if' statements within a LINQ queries 'where' statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760935/implementing-conditional-if-statements-within-a-linq-queries-where-statement)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Personally I wouldn't do that inside the `Where` clause as it means you are passing the `suply` variable to your database.

```
var q = _db.Tbl_Product
    .Where(model => model.DateReg == startdate 
                 && model.DateReg == enddate
                 && model.ProductName.Contains(productname));

if(suply == 1)
{
    q = q.Where(model => model.Suply > 0);
}
else
{
    q = q.Where(model => model.Suply == 0);
}
```

However, if you're really adamant that you want to do it all at once:

```
.Where(model => (suply == 1 && model.Suply > 0)
             || (suply != 1 && model.Suply == 0));
```